# Proved that the given set is not closed in the function space $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

The problem is actually taken from Davidson's Real analysis:

> Prove that the set $S= \{ F:F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt, ||f|| \leq 1 ,\, f\in \mathcal{C}([0,1])\}$ is not closed.

This means we should find a sequence $(F_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $S$ that converges uniformly to a function $F \not \in S$. Since every $F_n$ is continuous, the function $F$ should also be continuous, by uniform convergence. However, I have totally no idea how to construct such sequence.   I'd like to get some hints. Thanks!

Comment: You can easily construct a sequence of continuous absolutely continuous functions that converges uniformly to Cantor function which is not absolutely continuous...

Answer (score 1):

Note that, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, a function $F$ is in $S$ if and only if ist is continuously differentiable, $F(0)=0$ and it satisfies $|F_0^\prime(x)|\le 1\,\forall x $.

So you should try to find a function $F_0$ with $F_0(0)=0$ which is continuous but not $C^1$, and a sequence of $C^1$ functions $F_n$ with $F_n(0)=0$ and $||F_n^\prime||\le 1$ converging uniformly to $F_0$. The most nasty task will be to ensure the bound on $F_n^\prime$

Comment: Take a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $[0,1), $ converging to $1,$ with $a_1=0.$ We can find a continuous strictly  increasing $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1,$ such that $g$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1)$, and $g'(a_n)=0$ for each $n,$ and $\max \{g'(x): x\in (a_n,a_{n+1})\}=1$ for each $n.$ Now let $F_n(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in [0,a_n]$ and let $F_n(x)=g(a_n)$ for $x\in [a_n,1].$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I deliberately only tried to give a hint, since the OP asked for a hint only. Despite of this I have no doubt that a hint on how to find a sequence which implies the desired conclusion will be appreciated by the OP.  A possibly minor point in your construction proposal is that, if $g$ is a continuously differentiable function with $g(0)=0$,  $|g^\prime(x)|\le 1 $ for every $x$, and $ g^\prime(a) =0$ for some $a\in (0,1)$, then I believe it will follow that  $g(1) < 1$ (I assume you want to claim that your sequence converges uniformly to $F(x) =x$?)

Comment: Uhmm, you want to claim your sequence converges to $g$, I wanted to write...

Comment: I should not have  said $1=g(1)$. As you said , $g(1)<1.$ Then $F_n$ converges uniformly to $g$. And $g'(x)$ has a discontinuity at $x=1$.